# Python sqlite3: Update all records with sum of passed parameter and current field value

Tags: python, sqlite

Trying to update all records with the sum of each existing field value plus a parameter being passed. If the field in record A = 4 and record B = 5, I want to update all records so A = 4 + X and B = 5 + X. This way I can quickly increment all record values by a given number (X). So far I can't figure out how to get the update statement to expand the parameter being passed.

I can add hard coded value with this line: `c.execute("UPDATE level SET sell = sell + 1;")` The code below works as is.
But when I try to pass a value with the line `update_sell(1)` to `def update_sell(margin):` and reference the value passed like so, `c.execute("UPDATE level SET sell = sell + margin;")` it fails. What am I missing here?

Total python noob here.

Script to run:

```
#MainScript.py
import sqlite3
from LevelClass import level

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE level (
            buy integer,
            sell integer,
            quan integer
            )""")

def insert_level(level):
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO level VALUES (:buy, :sell, :quan)", {'buy': level.buy, 'sell': level.sell, 'quan': level.quan})

def get_level_by_sell(sell):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM level WHERE sell=:sell", {'sell': sell})
    return c.fetchall()

def update_sell(margin):
    with conn:
        # below works with "sell + 1", but fails with "sell + margin"
        c.execute("UPDATE level SET sell = sell + 1;")

trans_1 = level(1, 5, 50)
trans_2 = level(2, 10, 60)

insert_level(trans_1)
insert_level(trans_2)

# value to pass to update_sell as var "margin"
update_sell(1)

find = get_level_by_sell(6)
print(find)

find = get_level_by_sell(11)
print(find)

conn.close()
```

class:

```
# saved as LevelClass.py
class level:
    def __init__(self, buy, sell, quan):
        self.buy = buy
        self.sell = sell
        self.quan = quan

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Level('{}', '{}', {})".format(self.buy, self.sell, self.quan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're forgetting the `:` for the update function. This works for me.

```
def update_sell(margin):
    with conn:
        # below works with "sell + 1", but fails with "sell + margin"
        #c.execute("UPDATE level SET sell = sell + 1")
        c.execute("UPDATE level SET sell = sell + :margin", {"margin":margin})
```

Comment: Why is `{"margin": margin}` needed?

Comment: Margin still needed to be inserted into the prepared sql statement. You had the statement built, {'margin':margin} tells SQLites api to safely inject that variable into the sql so it can be processed.